# Trying to represent a Network using the "igraph" package on R, can't add a named independent node

Tags: r, igraph, sna

So I'm trying to represent a large network that is composed of other smaller networks.

In order to do this I try and create each one of the networks individually with the intention of inserting them all into an object later on, an example of these sub networks:

> USDA_APHIS <- graph(c("Paula Morales", "Mario Ambrosino"),
> directed = F)

I noticed that some of this sub networks are **composed of a single node**.

> CARICOM <-graph(c("Shaun Baugh"))

I have no clue on how to represent those since I can't use this expression with a single object.

Does anyone have an idea on how to proceed? Is there amore efficient way to go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a graph with one vertex, by creating an empty graph and adding one vertex.

```
library(igraph)
g = make_empty_graph()
g = add.vertices(g, 1, name="Shaun Baugh")
plot(g)
```

[image: Graph with one vertex]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer !